# Application to Grant Temporary Permissions

Tags: authentication, ldap

Looking for recommendations on an application that would sit on top of LDAP to provide the following functionality:  the ability to assign privileges to a user or group for a specific role or action for a specified length of time.

**A user story for this would be:**

*"I would like to be able to grant users access to perform some specific function for a limited amount of time."*

**An example of this would be:**

*"Grant root access on host12345 for user john.smith until 2011-12-14 1500 EST"*

I have looked on Google, etc. and found nothing suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenLDAP that is done via the Dynamic Objects overlay. Create a role object in the normal way, with the user as a member, but add the object class 'dynamicObject', and then use the extended operation [whose name I will look up in a minute] to set the expiry time.